# SQL Server 2012 GROUP BY must have at least one column that is not an outer reference- I only have inner joins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Hi I have been trying to solve this problem for two days. The above error message:

> Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 21 Each GROUP BY expression must
>   contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO: total prescriptions for each patient by hospital stay (patients_records record), listing first, last, patient record begin and end dates (for each stay), and total of prescriptions

I have searched the web, stackoverflow similar questions (which most or all seem to involve variables or constants).  I am stumped and could really use some help. My query doesn't use any outer joins, and I have tried removing all but the 'TotalOfPresc' column from the group by.  I am a beginner- please be gentle. Here is my code:

```
USE [BestHospitalDB];

SELECT PATIENTS.Last, PATIENTS.First, 
    Presc.PrescQuantity * Meds.PrescPrice As 'TotalOfPresc', 
    pr.SubmissionDate, pr.DischargeDate

FROM 
    PATIENTS AS p, 
    [PRESCRIPTIONS] AS Presc, 
    [PRESC_MEDS] AS Meds, 
    PATIENTS_RECORDS AS pr

INNER JOIN
    PATIENTS ON pr.PatientID = PATIENTS.[PatientID]

INNER JOIN
    PRESCRIPTIONS ON PRESCRIPTIONS.PatientsRecordsID = pr.PatientsRecordsID
INNER JOIN
    PRESC_MEDS ON PRESCRIPTIONS.PrescPresc_MedsID = PRESC_MEDS.Presc_MedsID

GROUP BY PATIENTS.First, PATIENTS.Last, pr.SubmissionDate, pr.DischargeDate, 'TotalOfPresc'
```

Comment: Edit your question and explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot group by a constant value.  Your query doesn't make sense in several ways.  I assume you intend something like this:

```
SELECT p.Last, p.First, 
       SUM(px.PrescQuantity * m.PrescPrice) As TotalOfPresc
FROM PATIENTS_RECORDS pr INNER JOIN
     PATIENTS p
     ON pr.PatientID = PATIENTS.[PatientID] INNER JOIN
     PRESCRIPTIONS px
     ON px.PatientsRecordsID = pr.PatientsRecordsID INNER JOIN
     PRESC_MEDS pm
    ON px.PrescPresc_MedsID = pm.Presc_MedsID
GROUP BY p.First, p.Last;
```

Some words of advice:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  You have the proper join syntax, why do you also want unnecessary Cartesian products?
- Don't use single quotes to name columns.  You'll just confuse yourself -- that is the specific problem you are encountering.
- Only aggregate by the keys that define a single row in the output.  If you use `GROUP BY`, you usually also want aggregation functions.

Comment: thank you for the advice on several fronts. 1. the single quotes Thank You.  2. commas in the from clause. 3. QUESTION 1. When you say, "Only aggregate by the keys that define a single row in the output. If you use GROUP BY, you usually also want aggregation functions," I assumed you meant the TotalOfPresc. Is that not an aggregation function? QUESTION 2. What column is not an outer reference? And, what about the single quotes cuased that message? QUESTION 3. I am sorry- which of my terms is a constant? (yeah, super dumb).  Thanks again for the clear, concise answer. They are extremely helpful

Comment: @nascent_coder . . . The root cause of the aggregation problem is `'TotalOfPresc'` in the `GROUP BY`.  This is just a string, not a column reference.

Comment: Thank you! I really was confused about that. This outer reference stuff is not clear.  The use of 'constant' seems to be different here than in my other programming languages- if you could shed some light that, too would be awesome.

Comment: @nascent_coder . . . The use of a constant in a `group by` causes this strange error.